# Villager socializing range

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The minecraft wiki [states](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Movement_patterns):

> Occasionally, two villagers may stop, and turn to look at each other, in a behavior called socializing, in which they will stare at another villager for a few seconds at a time.

How long is the range of this interaction? How many blocks can at most be between the two villagers for this to occur?

Answer (score 1):

After seeing this question I had to test it, my experiment gave an answer of upto 8 blocks between 2 villagers.
Hope this helps.

Comment: How did you perform this experiment. Please explain.